# Fails to recognize the .equals(String) from the Scanner's Input

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

**- Introduction:**
Hello, I was writing a simple program to practice. The program is gonna be a Password Generator. It's at very initial phase. While I was testing my codes, I ran into a problem. I googled and was able find similar cases, but I couldn't figure it out still.

**- The Problem:**
The problem starts couple lines after **While(Spec == 0)** When a user inputs Y or N in the scanner, it's supposed to fall under 'else if' statement and print out a number to output screen, however it keeps printing "Please Type Y or N". That means it's passing my 'else if' statements as incorrect match. How do I fix this?

**- What I've tried:**
I tried Nc.toString().equals("Y"), I also tried other small codes that people shared but they were simply wrong or did not work.

**- Current Outputs:**

```
Sys: How long will the Password be? (Numbers only)
User: 5
Sys: Do you want to include Special Characters? (Y/N)
User: Y
Sys: Please type Y or N
Sys: Do you want to include Special Characters? (Y/N)
User: N
Sys: Please type Y or N
Sys: Do you want to include Special Characters? (Y/N)
User: Yes
Sys: Please type Y or N
Sys: Do you want to include Special Characters? (Y/N)
User: 5
Sys: Please type Y or N!
Sys: Do you want to include Special Characters? (Y/N)
```

**- Expected Outputs:**

```
Case 1
    Sys: How long will the Password be? (Numbers only)
    User: 5
    Sys: Do you want to include Special Characters? (Y/N)
    User: Y
    Sys: 1

Case 2
    Sys: Do you want to include Special Characters? (Y/N)
    User: N
    Sys: 2

Case 3
    Sys: Do you want to include Special Characters? (Y/N)
    User: Yes
    Sys: Please type Y or N

Case 4
    Sys: Do you want to include Special Characters? (Y/N)
    User: 5
    Sys: Please type Y or N!
    Sys: Do you want to include Special Characters? (Y/N)
```

**- Full code:**

```
// This is what I have currently.

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.math.*;

public class Main {

    // Ask questions: how long char, include special letters or numbers.

    // How long PW gonna be
    private static int Char = 0; 

    // Special Letter Y = 1, N = 2
    private static int Spec = 0; 

    // Include Number? Y = 1, N = 2
    private static int Num = 0; 

    public static void main(String[] args){

        // While character is 0, it's looping until value changes
        while(Char == 0){

            // Reads the user input
            Scanner Sc = new Scanner(System.in);

            // Asks the question to the user
            System.out.println("How long will the Password be? (Numbers only)");

            // If it has an integer
            if(Sc.hasNextInt()){ 
                Char = Sc.nextInt();
            } 

            // If it doesn't have an integer
            else {
                System.out.println("Please type number only!");
            }
        }

        // While Spec is 0, it's looping until value changes
        while(Spec == 0){

            // Reads the user input
            Scanner Nc = new Scanner(System.in);

            // Asks the question to the user
            System.out.println("Do you want to include Special Characters? (Y/N)");

            // If it has an integer, prompts to redo
            if(Nc.hasNextInt()){
                System.out.println("Please type Y or N!");
            }

            // If user types Y, Yes then changes spec to 1
            else if (Nc.equals("Y")) {
                Spec = 1;
                System.out.println(Spec);
            }

            // If user types N, No then changes spec to 2
            else if (Nc.equals("N")) {
                Spec = 2;
                System.out.println(Spec);
            }

            // If neither above, prompts to redo
            else {
                System.out.println("Please type Y or N");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `Nc` is a `Scanner`, it will *never* be equal to the literal string `"Y"` or `"N"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read a word from a Scanner, use next():

```
String userInput = Nc.next();
if(userInput.equals("Y")){
    // some code
}
```

Comment: I did what you wrote, but for some reason, it's making me type twice to recognize my inputs. Why is that?

Comment: Sorry. Try using nextLine()